# Change app component style from any child component - Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I want to change the background of app component (parent component) from the child component.

Let's say I have two group of components, one group will be primary component which be directly accessed from app 
component menu and other group is secondary component which will be accessed from primary component menus/link. 
so here I want to change the app component background based on primary and secondary components loaded

https://plnkr.co/edit/t97ZyDz9wfGuPEzuo8J3?p=preview

app.component.css

```
.page-background
{
     background-color:#FFF0F5;
}
.page-background-hero
{
    background-color:white;
}
.page-background-crisis
{
    background-color:wheat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using styles property in the child component and wrap the content with a div element specifying a background color.

**CRISIS CENTER CHILD COMPONENT**

```
@Component({
  template:  `
    <div class="red">
        <h2>CRISIS CENTER</h2>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [RouterOutlet],
  providers:  [CrisisService],
  styles:[`.blue{background-color:red} `]

})
```

**HEROS LIST CHILD COMPONENT**

```
@Component({
  template: `
  <div class="yellow">
        <h2>HEROES</h2>
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="#hero of heroes"
            (click)="onSelect(hero)">
            <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
          </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
  `
    styles:[`.yellow{background-color:yellow} `]
})
```

**[UPDATED PLUNK](https://plnkr.co/edit/l5by32HlKwtb9ULzlREi)**

Comment: Thanks, I need to update the app component (parent) style

Comment: Yes based on the child component loaded, parent component style should be toggled

Comment: I can't understand your question please elaborate

Comment: Setting app component background based on child component displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a [shared service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) for this kind of parent-child communication.

The parent could subscribe to the service, with the child pushing the background style etc information when it loads (via `ngOnInit`)

Another alternative would be to have the parent component access the child via `ContentChildren` to determine which colour to change the background to.

Comment: Thx, Looks like possible answer, will give a try.